# ContentNote and DataLoader - permission

Tags: permissions, contentnote, dataloader.io

I have a question, I wanted to delete old notes from ContentNote object using DataLoader. Part of the notes I was able to delete, but with the rest I got the message

> ERROR: insufficient access rights on object id

Looking at such a note from the Notes tab I have the right only as **viewer**, I can't delete it I can only **Remove from record**. Does anyone know what permission set could be responsible for this? In settings I have access to **all data** checked.

The difference between the notes that I was able to remove and those that I did not is that the ones with error were imported from our old CRM system. The deleted ones were already created in SF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you need is the "Modify All Data" permission and to delete the ContentDocumentLinks associated with the ContentNote before moving to delete the ContentNote.